# prediction scores on test vs train dataset different with/without gridsearchcv

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, gridsearchcv

I am exploring the use of GridSearchCV from sklearn to predict data. After the fit of the data using RandomForestRegressor, I calculate the score (MSE) for the test and the train data. I can see there is a huge difference between the MSE of train and the MSE of test (even if the scores should be similar).

Here is the code:

```
# split dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)


# Create Regressors Pipeline
pipeline_estimators = Pipeline([
                                ('RandomForest', RandomForestRegressor()),
                                ])

param_grid = [{'RandomForest__n_estimators': np.linspace(50, 100, 3).astype(int)}]

search = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipeline_estimators,
                    param_grid = param_grid,
                    scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error',
                    cv = 2,)


search.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_test_predicted = search.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
y_train_predicted = search.best_estimator_.predict(X_train)

print('MSE test predict', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_predicted))
print('MSE train predict',metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_predicted))
```

The OUT are:

- MSE test predict 0.0021045875412650343
- MSE train predict 0.000332850878980335

IF I don't use Gridsearchcv but a FOR loop for the differet 'n_estimators', the MSE scores obtained for the predicted test and the train are very close.

To add more detail related to the 'FOR loop' explanation, this is by using simple approach, see code below:

```
n_estimators = np.linspace(50, 100, 3).astype(int)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, 
random_state=0)

mse_train = []
mse_test = []
for val_n_estimators in n_estimators:

    regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = val_n_estimators)

    regressor.fit(X, y) 

    y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

    y_test_predicted  = regressor.predict(X_test)
    y_train_predicted = regressor.predict(X_train)

    mse_train.append(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_predicted))
    mse_test.append(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_test_predicted)) code here
```

For this code, the **mse_train** and **mse_test** are very similar. But using the Gridseachcv (see code on the top of the post), they are not similar.
Any suggestions?

Why there is such scores difference using GridSearchCV?

Thank you.

Marc

Comment: what do you mean by "FOR loop for the differet 'n_estimators'" ? You ran the cross validation using a for loop? In anyway case, they should not differ that much. You can try different splits to see how much your MSE differs

Comment: I added a new section in the question related to the FOR loop approach.

Comment: your for loop and gridsearchcv are not equivalent. You fitted the whole dataset in the for loop part

Comment: I missed that. Thank you for the quick solution!